# PHP ifelse makes the post values to database null with upload

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I try to make an upload form and post some values to database. I write this code, but when I echo it, it gives a result and when I check the database, I get values null - there are no values... the file uploaded and was renamed, but no values were send to database.

table name: companies

columns:

---

CO_ID
company_name
company_sign_1
company_sign_name_1
company_sign_name_p_1
company_sign_2
company_sign_name_2
company_sign_name_p_2
company_sign_3
company_sign_name_3
company_sign_name_p_3
company_logo_1
company_logo_2
company_logo_3

---

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showfield(name){
if(name=='company_sing_1'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 1:<BR><input type="text" name="company_sign_name_1" /><BR>Manager Position 1:<BR><input type="text" name="company_sign_name_p_1" />';
}else if(name=='company_sing_2'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 2:<BR><input type="text" name="company_sign_name_2" /><BR>Manager Position 2:<BR><input type="text" name="company_sign_name_p_2" />';
}else if(name=='company_sing_3'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 3:<BR><input type="text" name="company_sign_name_3" /><BR>Manager Position 3:<BR><input type="text" name="company_sign_name_p_3" />';
}
    else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}

</script>


<?php
$newfilenamepath = "$filepath_d" . "$filename_d";

$company_name= ($_POST['company_name'])?$_POST['company_name']:'';
$upload_type= ($_POST['upload_type'])?$_POST['upload_type']:'';

  if ($upload_type = "company_sing_1") {
    $company_sign_name_1= ($_POST['company_sign_name_1'])?$_POST['company_sign_name_1']:'';
    $company_sign_name_p_1= ($_POST['company_sign_name_p_1'])?$_POST['company_sign_name_p_1']:'';
    mysql_query("update companies set  $upload_type='".$newfilenamepath."', company_sign_name_1='".$company_sign_name_1."', company_sign_name_p_1='".$company_sign_name_p_1."' where CO_ID='".$company_name."'");
  } elseif ($upload_type = "company_sing_2") {
    $company_sign_name_2= ($_POST['manager2'])?$_POST['manager2']:'';
    $company_sign_name_p_2= ($_POST['manager2_pos'])?$_POST['manager2_pos']:'';
    mysql_query("update companies set  $upload_type='".$newfilenamepath."', company_sign_name_2='".$company_sign_name_2."', company_sign_name_p_2='".$company_sign_name_p_2."' where CO_ID='".$company_name."'");
  } elseif ($upload_type = "company_sing_3") {
    $company_sign_name_3= ($_POST['manager3'])?$_POST['manager3']:'';
    $company_sign_name_p_3= ($_POST['manager3_pos'])?$_POST['manager3_pos']:'';
    mysql_query("update companies set  $upload_type='".$newfilenamepath."', company_sign_name_3='".$company_sign_name_3."', company_sign_name_p_3='".$company_sign_name_p_3."' where CO_ID='".$company_name."'");
  } else {
    mysql_query("update companies set  $upload_type='".$newfilenamepath."' where CO_ID='".$company_name."'"); 
  }

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">


<select name="company_name">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please Select Name Of Company</option>
<?php
$company_lists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY CO_ID DESC");
while ($row_com_list = mysql_fetch_array($company_lists)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row_com_list['CO_ID'] . "'>" . $row_com_list['company_name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</select><BR /><BR />


<input name="file" type="file" size="20" /><BR /><BR />


<select name="upload_type"  onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please Select Type Of Upload</option>
<option value="company_logo">Add A Logo</option>
<option value="company_logo_2">Add Second Logo</option>
<option value="company_logo_2">Add Third Logo</option>
<option value="company_sing_1">Add Sign For Manager 1</option>
<option value="company_sing_2">Add Sign For Manager 2</option>
<option value="company_sing_3">Add Sign For Manager 3</option>
</select><BR /><BR />
<div id="div1"></div></BR></BR>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

What is the problem and what can we do?

edit:

when I fill the form and echo it and break at the first if I get this:

```
    echo $upload_type;
    echo "//////";
    echo $company_sign_name_1;
    echo "//////";
    echo $company_sign_name_p_1;
    echo "//////";
    echo $newfilenamepath;
    echo "//////";
    echo $company_name;
    break;
```

company_sing_1//////Abdulrahman Nahhas//////General Manager//////uploads/9-20140920-0494829001411172658.png//////2

this mean it take the form but not send the values to mysql I test the echo in the second elseif it gives me nothing.

Comment: How is `$filepath_d` being defined? Far as I can see, it's a stray variable. Not to mention `$_FILES['file']` is missing.

Comment: $filepath_d = $out['filepath'];

Comment: if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
      //Success
      $out['filepath'] = $path;
      $out['filename'] = $newname;
  
$filepath_d = $out['filepath'];

$filename_d = $out['filename'];

Comment: when I fill the form and echo it and break at the first if I get this:  company_sing_1//////Abdulrahman Nahhas//////General Manager//////uploads/9-20140920-0494829001411172658.png//////2 this mean it take the form but not send the values to mysql I test the echo in the second elseif it gives me nothing.

Comment: Please add your code to question itself using the edit button, as its not properly readable within comments. How does the final query look like, have you checked the last error using `mysql_error` ?
Also be sure to educate yourself about `sql injection`...

Comment: I will check all the system after editing for sql injection. but i need to learn it also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `$upload_type` is `company_sing_1` etc instead of `company_sign_1` etc.  You have no fields in your db named `company_sing_1` etc... Fix the naming and you'll fix your problem.

Comment: I write the columns in the table and there is company_sing_1 field and etc. the company_sing_1 name is taken from the form field